# How can I return an object from MongoDB that contain an array with ids from other collection?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Hello guys I have the following query but it returns only an array with skills instead the object with array inside

To make it clearer

EndorsedSkill response

```
{
    _id
    userId
    skills: [
        {_id},
        {_id}
    ]
}
```

Skill response

```
{
    _id
    name
}
```

What I want to receive is

```
{
    _id
    userId
    skills: [
        {_id, name},
        {_id, name}
    ]
}
```

The query looks like this

```
getUsersSkills: async (_, { u_id, ...args }, { user }) => {
    try {
      await requireAuth(user);
      const p1 = Skill.find({}).sort({ createdAt: -1 });
      const p2 = EndorsedSkill.findOne({ userId: u_id });
      const [skills, endorsed] = await Promise.all([p1, p2]);

      const checkEndorsedSkills = await skills.reduce((arr, skill) => {
        const s = skill.toJSON();

        if (endorsed.skills.some(s => s.equals(skill._id))) {
          arr.push({
            ...s,
            endorsed: true
          });
        } else {
          arr.push({
            ...s,
            endorsed: false
          });
        }

        return arr;
      }, []);

      const endorsedSkills = checkEndorsedSkills.filter(
        skill => skill.endorsed === true
      );

      return endorsedSkills;
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please mention that how you connected to mongoDB?